# Html table bug with background image while resizing browser

Tags: html, css, html-table

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/751373/pexels-photo-751373.jpeg');
}

#main {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <table>
     <tr>
       <td>d</td>
       <td>a</td>
       <td>m</td>
       <td>n</td>
       <td>b</td>
       <td>u</td>
       <td>g</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have simple table with the background image for TD in a centered div. When I will resize the browser window width with a mouse (Chrome, Opera) then a white spaces appears between TD.

How can I solve it?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gauh9s7t/

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4h5bEOS3jE

Comment: If you are using an image with solid color, why not using `background-color`?

Comment: Do you have to use a table?

Comment: Look into sub-pixel rounding.

Comment: @marcelo2605 that is just a example. I need to use my own background image.

Comment: @Peter yes, look there for the table: http://rotaxmame.cz/assault

Answer (score 0):

Is not a bug, it is about your background-image:

```
url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/751373/pexels-photo-751373.jpeg');
```

If you replace this property with background color every td from your table will be fine.

Comment: What have the white spaces to do with background image? Yes, background color works ok, but I need to use background image with repeated property.